# Run two commands in cron

Tags: linux, terminal, cron

I need to run a task every hour . I first change directory to the path where script is and then operate that script. So I try to use a cron job as :

```
59 * * * * cd /home/sansal/Scripts && sudo ./usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/003
```

I added that line to crontab. But I cant make sure if it is true. And I dont see any output in terminal about that.

Comment: You don't need to change to the directory, just use the absolute path of the script `/home/sansal/Scripts/usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/003`

Comment: So : 59 * * * * /home/sansal/Scripts/usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/003 ?

Comment: Isn't my answer clear about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the full path is defintely better then first using cd. To get the result of the cronjob, you could just output to file like this:

```
59 * * * * /home/sansal/Scripts/usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/003 &>> /home/sansal/usbreset.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the script failed with `||`

```
59 * * * * /home/sansal/Scripts/usbreset /dev/bus/usb/002/003 || echo "usbreset failed"
```

`cron` automatically sends email with any output of the command.

Comment: You can also redirect the output of the `echo` command to a file. That doesn't depend on your e-mail being configured correctly.

Comment: @KeithThompson how can I do that?

Comment: @ŞansalBirbaş See the other answer. Don't you know basic shell syntax for doing output redirection?

Comment: @Barmar echo usbreset.log ?

Comment: @ŞansalBirbaş `echo usbreset failed >> usbreset.log`

Comment: @Barmar I did not know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Then it's time for you to read a tutorial on shell scripting. SO is not a substitute for learning the basics.